How to integrate Subxt with frontier?
I want the transaction to be happen through subxt on frontier node template.
I'm getting this error in this process:
Metadata error: The generated code is not compatible with the node 
How to solve this issue?
Thanks

subxt has added an example how to talk to it with frontier/moonbeam here
